# Fitnesse - How to define a wiki or slim variable from an environment variable or file?

Tags: variables, passwords, slim, fitnesse

I have a password token (that changes every few minutes) that I need to pass to my SLIM tests.
I can store this token in either a text file or environment variable. But once I have that password saved, I need to get my test cases to see the value. So is it possible to get a value from an environment variable or a file into a fitnesse test case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read a file or environment from your fixture (Java, .Net or ..) code. I created a [FileFixture](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/blob/master/src/main/java/nl/hsac/fitnesse/fixture/slim/FileFixture.java) that reads files ([sample usage](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/master/wiki/FitNesseRoot/HsacExamples/SlimTests/UtilityFixtures/FileFixture.wiki)). It may be of use or could provide inspiration...

The wiki, if it was started after the environment variable was set, could access it as a symbol (i.e. `${MY_PASSWORD_TOKEN}`), but I don't expect you need that.

By the way: if your password token changes that often it might be better/easier to write some fixture code to retrieve the current password directly, instead of first having to store it in an environment variable or file before you start your test.

Comment: FileFixture is exactly what I was trying out on friday (it looks like it came with your package on Github). But I couldnt find anything in the examples on assigning the value in a text file to a variable. For example, if file.txt contains 123456, I can do something like | $variable= | text in | e:\file.txt | but that just sets $variable to "$variable=123456", where all I need obviously is 123456.

Comment: Have you double checked the usage of `$variable=`? The variable should contain only the contents of the file (i.e. if you pass the variable to a fixture method using `$variable` the fixture method should receive `123456`)

Comment: I use it in a header: | set value | $variable | for header | Authorization |. When I run the test case, under FileFixture it echos $variable<-[eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGci] and then on the header creation, it echos $variable->[eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGci]. So I'm not sure why the variable name, ->, and the brackets are being added after the variable is created.

Comment: That's just display in the wiki/test report. The actual header value is just the value. You could check using a debugger. If it's not file an issue on GitHub